# How to use only one spring test context when @ContextConfiguration(loader=MyLoader.class) is used

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I need to control creating of the test context. So, for my test classes I set `@ContextConfiguration(loader=MyLoader.class)` where `MyLoader extends AnnotationConfigContextLoader`. The problem is that for every test class instance of MyLoader is created and that loader instance creates new context. So, I have a new context for every test class. However, this is not what I need. Is it possible to make spring-test create only one context for all test classes at the same time controlling loading process?

To make it clear, I use loader as I need to set context config class dynamically. I didn't find a way to do:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classProvider=ContextConfigClassProvider.class)//this is what I need
public class FooServiceIT {

    @Test
    public void t() {
        System.out.println("TEST");
    }
}
```

so, I use loader.

Comment: It will already cache things **but** if there is something different (the config-classes to use) it will create a new one. Also the fact that you need to set things dynamically feels like you are doing things in your test you shouldn't be doing in the first place.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, you are right. It is cached. I thought that Loader had to be cached, but as you said loaded result was cached. If you make an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring Test framework already caches the result of loading the context. What is important that the cache-key is constructed of several parts (see [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching)). As long as those parts are the same it will use the already loaded cache and not re-load again.